# Issue with styles on the latest version of Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Today i've updated google-chrome to the latest version (Version 75.0.3770.142). And have next issue:
When i try load page with input, wrong styles set to input (to wit - font-size of input), but when i click at any place on the documents - styles sets to input;

Input before clicking on page:

[image]

Input after clicking on any place of document:

[image]

I tried set font-size with !import, tried set font-size inline as well. But nothing helped.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to bug introduced in Chrome version 75.0.3770.142.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=984495&can=1&q=input%20font%20size&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified